# How to upload web data to Firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I can't get this data to upload to firebase. Am I using firebase-firestore wrong because it has been renamed? The web console says "firebase.firestore is not a function" Firebase config is removed in code for your infomation.

```html
<body>
<form>
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your name..">
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email..">

  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email..">

  <label for="message">Subject</label>
  <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>

  <button id="submit_msg" type="button">Submit</button>
</form>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Importing Firebase into my project

```html
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
         https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.2/firebase-storage.js"></script>
```

Comment: is your firebaseConfig set somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I removed it because it woud not let me post. Code was too long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always make sure you are using libraries that are the same version. This is because their internal code has changed over the years. In this case, you are trying to use the Firestore v6.2.4 addin with the v8.3.2 main library where it's reporting an error that it can't attach itself to the main library.

```html
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.2/firebase-storage.js"></script>
```

Comment: So how do I fix my issue? I need to update storage? Could you give an example thx

Comment: There's no need to change your code aside from removing the URLs that contain `https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.4/` and using the ones posted in this answer